# NerdTree or FZF ignores .env files

Tags: vim, nerdtree, fzf

Either nerdtree or fzf ignores .env, I have a .env in my working folder, but I can't find it with fzf nor in nerdtree.

Here's my vimrc:
https://github.com/dipzera/nvim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For NERDTree, try

```
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
```

For fzf, it depends on what command you're running/if you're using `ag` or `rg`, but you'll need to add a "hidden" flag to the arguments. For instance,

```
let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='find -L'
```

will make it so that `:FZF` will let you search for hidden files using `find`. You'll want to modify that to use whatever program you prefer instead. I believe you can also set this variable in your `.bashrc` instead of in your `init.vim` but that's up to you.